# Select row in tableview programmatically when row is not visible

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have to select one by one cell in a tableview and "execute" this row to show their detailviewcontroller. I use the following code. Everything is working as it should be, as long as the next row to be executed is visible in the screen. Is the next cell in the red zone the user has to manually scroll to this cell and than it get's executed.

Any help

```
- (void)showNextExercise:(NSNumber *)nextOne{
int nextRow = [(NSNumber *)nextOne intValue];
NSLog(@"Next Row: %i", nextRow);


//Auto Start next Exercise //
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:nextRow inSection:0];



if ([self.tableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
    [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

//[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

if ([self.tableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
    [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}


[self performSelector:@selector(performSelectorWithDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];

//END Auto Start next Exercise //
}



-(void)performSelectorWithDelay{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:nil];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (![executedExercises containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[object valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description]]]) {
        [executedExercises addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[object valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description]]];

    }    
    [autoExecutedExercises addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[object valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description]]];
    //[autoExecutedExercises addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:indexPath.row]];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        long warmUpTime = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"WarmUpBackup"];
        NSLog(@"warmupBackUp: %li", warmUpTime);


    }

}
```

[Red Zone Image](http://www.boulder-trainer.com/images/rows.png)

Answer (score 0):

What did you do exactly in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath? Due to the reuse cell mechanism, invisible cells may not exist if you try to get them in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I updated my question, so you can now see my didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Don't abuse the UI system. You don't need to tell the table view delegate that a cell is going to be and then has been tapped on, you can just present the view controllers you require directly (call the method that presents without bothering the delegate).

You have the data that goes into the table view and you should be using that directly. Funnelling everything through the UI code is a burden and an application of knowledge and cross coupling in the code where there should be none.

If you wanted to show the table rows as selected, set a flag for the selected item in the data model (band scroll / reload the table). Now when the table is refreshed you can mark the cell.

Comment: Hello Wain, I don't get it, how can I present the viewcontroller directly, without having the indexpath.row? For your understanding, it's the following app https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/boulder-trainer/id770657161?mt=8

Comment: You have (or create) the index path. You don't need the table view for that.

Comment: Do you have a link to an example? Because I don't have a clue how this should work. The user has a "master" tableview with several exercises. He has to select an exercise and he will be lead to a detailview. After the exercise is done, the detailview will be dismissed automatically. If the user has set up a break time for the LAST executed exercise, than (but only than) the next exercise (detailviewcontroller) is going to be executed automatically. So from my point of view, I have to use a tableview controller.

Comment: The code you have in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, move it to another method which takes the `indexPath` as a parameter. Call that method from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Also, call it from `showNextExercise:` (instead of calling the table delegate).